# Remove dot line rectangle surrounded hyper-link after click event

Tags: jquery

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/help-remove-dot-line.png?attredirects=0](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/help-remove-dot-line.png?attredirects=0)

Whenever a click event happen on a hyper-link, I will use JavaScript to toggle the display of a drop down menu. However, I realize there will be a dotted line rectangle surrounded the hyper-link still. May I know how I can explicitly remove the dotted line rectangle after the click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a {
outline:none;
}

will do the trick

Answer (score 7):

Put this into your CSS

a:focus { outline:none }